# Save class to firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My class is CredicardinfoObject.class

```
public class CreditcardinfoOjbect implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static String title;
    public static String startTime;
    public static String endTime;
    public static String day;

}
```

This class has only static proprieties. There is no instantiation needed.

In my **mainActivity.class**, I want to set the values of the class and then store this firebase database. This is my **mainActivity.class**.

```
    CreditcardinfoOjbect.title = "foo";
    CreditcardinfoOjbect.startTime = "bar";
    CreditcardinfoOjbect.day = "1";
    CreditcardinfoOjbect.endTime = "2";

    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    String uid = "";
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        uid = user.getUid();
    }
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("users").child(uid).child("account").child("creditcards");

    HashMap<String, Class<CreditcardinfoOjbect>> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("card", CreditcardinfoOjbect.class);
    ref.setValue("card",hashMap );
```

Unfortunatelly, this is not working. How can I store a the current value of a class in Firebase?

Comment: try getting the pojo class data into different variables and then adding it into firebase. While retriving data from Firebase make pojo class again

Comment: I guess You Need Setter and Getter

Comment: See my answer below. Let me know if it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to add to your POJO class, the no-argument constructor needed for Firebase and the public setters and public getters for each field like this:

```
public class CreditCardInfoObject implements Serializable {
    private String title;
    privat eString startTime;
    private String endTime;
    private String day;

    public CreditCardInfoObject() {}

    public String getTitle() {return title;}
    public void setTitle(String title) {this.title = title;}

    public String getStartTime() {return startTime;}
    public void setStartTime(String startTime) {this.startTime = startTime;}

    public String getEndTime() {return endTime;}
    public void setEndTime(String endTime) {this.endTime = endTime;}

    public String getDay() {return day;}
    public void setDay(String day) {this.day = day;}
}
```

Please note that you don't need static fields. Also note, that `i set all your fields as private`. In that case, setters and getters are not required.

Now, to set the value of your POJO class, you need to create a new instance of `CreditCardInfoObject` class and use the public setters. Having this new object, you can save it to the Firebase Realtime Database like this:

```
CreditcardinfoOjbect obj = new CreditcardinfoOjbect();
obj.setTitle("foo");
obj.setStartTime("bar");
obj.setEndTime("1");
obj.setDay("2");

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
String uid = "";
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    uid = user.getUid();
}
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("users").child(uid).child("account").child("creditcards");
ref.setValue(obj);
```

Comment: I find it strange that google doesn't mention about adding objects straight into the database. In the examples they always create `Map<String, Object>` and map the object into one before passing it in the `setValue()`. It's much simpler to just pass the object. Thanks for this example :)

Answer (score 2):

Try change your code in **CreditCardInfoObject** class

```
public class CreditCardInfoObject implements Serializable {

    public String title;
    public String startTime;
    public String endTime;
    public String day;

    public CreditCardInfoObject() {
    }

    public CreditCardInfoObject(String title, String startTime, String endTime, String day) {
        this.title = title;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
        this.day = day;
    }

    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("title", title);
        result.put("startTime", startTime);
        result.put("endTime", endTime);
        result.put("day", day);

        return result;
    }

}
```

Change your code in **MainActivity** like below

```
String title = "foo";
String startTime = "bar";
String endTime = "1";
String day = "2";

final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
String uid = "";
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    uid = user.getUid();
}

final Map<String, Object> dataMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
CreditCardInfoObject creditCardInfoObject = new CreditCardInfoObject(title,startTime,endTime,day);

DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("users").child(uid).child("account");
dataMap.put("creditcards", creditCardInfoObject.toMap());
ref.updateChildren(dataMap);
```

For more information: [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Hope it worked. Feel free to ask me anything.